# I want to use a text box to enter mathematical expressions

Tags: javascript, html, mathml

I would like to use a text box to enter mathematical expressions.

Like the site below.

https://www.mathpapa.com/factoring-calculator/
[image]

How can I embed such a formula bar?

Comment: You can make use of regex to identify the variables, numbers and subscripts

Comment: I might check this out here: https://www.mathjax.org/#apis. Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it renders Latex expressions and Mathoverflow uses it.